# Checking whether a point is inside a polygon

Tags: c#, opengl, math, opentk

I have made an object class and set the mouseEnter event on it. Object describes a process of creating a circle using opengl (here is drawing process function):

```
public void DrawCicrle()
        {
            GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.TriangleFan);
            GL.Color4(Color_);
            GL.Vertex2(X_, Y_);
            for (int i = 0; i < 360; i++)
            {
                GL.Vertex2(X_ + Math.Cos(i) * Radius_, Y_ + Math.Sin(i) * Radius_);

            }
            GL.End();

        }
```

Then I did a mouseEvent, but cant get the coordinates of cursor correctly. What are the correct conditions to get points in the arc of a circle?
This function returns a points, but with a little offset on the left side (X_ and Y_ are the center of a circle (double type) Radius_ is double type too):

```
public Point CursorLocation
        {
            get
            {
                return CursorLocation_;
            }
            set
            {
                this.CursorLocation_ = value;
                for (int i = 0; i < 360; i++)
                {
                    if (CursorLocation_.X <= X_ + Math.Cos(i) * Radius_ && CursorLocation_.Y<= Y_ + Math.Sin(i) * Radius_ && CursorLocation_.Y>=Y_-Radius_)
                    {
                        Enter(new Point(CursorLocation_.X, CursorLocation_.Y));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This isn't about events or the MouseEnter event, it's about math

Comment: Yes, but I discribed it for understanding what I did before faced with this problem

Comment: You don't draw a circle using System.Drawing either. You seem to be drawing a *polygon* in Unity? Use the *proper* tags and explain what you actually do, what the problem is otherwise you confuse people

Comment: ok! changed the tags. No, it is OpenTK

Comment: You *still* don't mention what libraries you used. Some of them allow you to check whether one shape intersects another or if a point is inside a shape. Why draw individual vertices for example, instead of a polygon that you could store and use to check for intersection? Googling for the method names returns results for Unity, OpenTK and other libraries

Comment: Anyway, [this question in math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198764/how-to-know-if-a-point-is-inside-a-circle) explains that the distance of any point inside the circle is less than the radius. You don't need to calculate vertex coordinates, just the distance between the center and the cursor

Comment: Apart from that, if you have a *lot* of shapes, it's too expensive to calculate distances. Many libraries provides ways to accelerate point-in-shape searches (again, what library are you using?). Such searches are used to speed up rendering, so the functionality may already be available

Comment: If you have to implement it from scrach, a rough way to speed up searches is to first check which shapes are inside the bounding box of a polygon. A point with X farther than (X_ ± Radius/2) is outside the circle no matter what

Comment: btw, should rename the question to say circle, not polygon - for polygons there are other algorithms (more simplistic one is to check each triangle, others use rays and/or checking on which subplanes defined by polygon side lines a test point lies)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition is dx * dx + dy * dy < R * R, where dx=Math.Abs(x-cx) and dy=Math.Abs(y-cy)

(x,y) is the cursor location and (cx,cy) the circle center

So you check the Euclidian distance between circle Center and some Point. To avoid square root calculation you just square both sides of comparison

Use <= if you also want to count-in the circle border

Comment: That's why the question is out of scope, already answered in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198764/how-to-know-if-a-point-is-inside-a-circle

Comment: Actually the math related forum won't probably care on what is the most appropriate way to check in a software program

Comment: This answer doesn't show how to do this in a program either

Comment: Actually it does mention Math.Abs and have a valid expression, using squared terms at both sides of expression to avoid Sqrt and also avoiding calling Sqr style custom functions that math people might suggest instead.

Comment: Just read the math people answer you mentioned. Sorry to say, mine here is way better for programmers of C#